# MYSQL Maria DB - Compare 2 tables A and B and update records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables A and B. I wanted to compare table A with table B and for any mismatched record I wanted to update the entire record from table A to Table B. We have 2 primary keys and have around 40 million records.

Can we achieve this in one SQL or Script? Or can I create temporary table(Table c) where I can write table A records which are mismatching and then update Table B with temporary Table C. This I would be doing in MY SQL workbench and using mariaDB DB.

Added additional information - I have 2 primary keys and 15 columns. So, Ideally have to match 13 columns and find mismatches assuming the primary key matches in both tables.

Please assist and appreciate for any feedback.

Comment: Do you know how to update? How to join? What are you stuck on?

Comment: I know how to pull/identify the mismatched records using left join but I need to update the mismatched records, probaly in 1 sql/script., thats where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to do an update left join of the B table to the A table, and update all columns in the former table with values from the latter.  Note that the `WHERE` clause checks to make sure that a record in B did *not* match to any record in A.

```
UPDATE TABLE_B b
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a
    ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
       a.col2 = b.col2     -- AND all other columns
SET b.col1 = a.col1,
    b.col2 = a.col2        -- AND set all other columns
WHERE a.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Tim - Should I add primary key columns in the where clause. Please assist.

Comment: @SATG123 This is a table structure question which wouldn't necessarily change my answer.  What is the problem then?

Comment: table a   
   
col1 col2 col3 col4
100 aaa bbb null
200 ccc ddd eee
300 fff null kkk
table b   
col1 col2 col3 col4
100 aaa ccc ddd
200 ccc ddd eee
300 ddd kkk mmm
400 nnn ppp www
   
output of table a should contain these values. Note col1 and col2 are primary values 
table a   
col1 col2 col3 col4
100 aaa ccc ddd
200 ccc ddd eee
300 ddd kkk mmm
400 nnn ppp www

Comment: Your comment is illegible.  What are you trying to say?